# Why using an adapted 15-pin SATA connector, my Hard Disk does not turn on?

Tags: usb, hard-disk, power-supply, sata, power

I have bought [this cable](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33019962132.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.25247ee1HCXL6P&algo_pvid=d512905c-5961-4975-824e-427518e0501f&algo_exp_id=d512905c-5961-4975-824e-427518e0501f-3&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2267143107414%22%7D) in order to use a separate USB adapter to power my desktop hard disk (3,5")

[image: USB to SATA]

At one end is a normal USB male connector, and on the other end is an adapted 15-pin plug. These are the connected pins, I believe. Which I think they are correct pinned

[image: SATA pinout]

Should I connect anything else to turn the hard disk on? Or should this be enough? Am I doing anything wrong?

There are many cables like the one in the image below, but what I want is to manage the data cable be independent from the power cable. Is that possible? I was looking for a cable 7-pin SATA male to USB male but I couldn't find any. I want to connect the disk to a Raspberry and use a different power adapter to make it work.

[image: data and power cable together]

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: a) This is not a hardware request, & would be a better fit for https://superuser.com/ b) You didn't tell us what HDD you're trying to power.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @tetsujin. I'm trying to power [this guy](https://www.amazon.com/Red-4TB-Internal-Hard-Drive/dp/B083XVY99B/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=nas+hdd&sr=8-2). Actually I'm looking for a hardware recommendation because actually my configuration is not working correctly. How can make this work?

Comment: It says on the product link *and* the picture you posted that it will not work on 3.5" drives, because USB doesn't have a 12V rail. You need a dock with its own power supply.

Comment: Aaah you are right @tetsujin, I'm kind of blind haha. I thought it would work because I have a Qualcomm Quick Charger with 12V, that uses USB cable. So I don't know why they say that USB does not have 12V rail ¿? Thin, I would go for something like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000027558331.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.7182746eU0R6nL&algo_pvid=b298c57f-ccd6-4065-977d-c9236315674b&algo_exp_id=b298c57f-ccd6-4065-977d-c9236315674b-3&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2210000000062274439%22%7D) with and adapter molex-SATA. Let's see if I don't blunder again

Comment: They say USB doesn't have a 12v rail… because it doesn't. It has 5v only. The Qualcomm must have some kind of step-up transformer.

Comment: Anyway I wonder if it would work if I use the pins from 10 to 15, instead of 4 to 9 and power with my Qualcomm charger @Tetsujin

Comment: It's your Qualcomm… & your right to test if the magic smoke leaks out when you try that ;)

Comment: Uhmm yes, you may be right @tet, it says 12V 1,5A. I need at least 2A I think to run the disk with stability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That device won't work on 3.5" HDD drives because USB-A doesn't have the 12v rail those drives need.
USB-C has various ways of delivering higher power, but  not USB-A.

The solution is an external power supply or something with USB-C with a PD specification.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only one I found, and its for old SATA and is from a dutch shop: https://www.dennisdeal.com/products/usb-2-0-naar-sata-ide-data-hard-drive-cable-voor-hdd-power-converter-adapter_1105778

Comment: Thanks for answering. As Tetsujin said in the comments I can't use that cable in my question with desktop hard disks. That was my mistake :/

Comment: Anyway I will need something similar to your suggestion to send just only the data through USB. I wonder why it is not very popular that kind of cable

Comment: I found [this one](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/4000479523983.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.1859334cNFttgS&algo_pvid=95073004-d4d4-4d4c-b63c-b4c5674d9595&algo_exp_id=95073004-d4d4-4d4c-b63c-b4c5674d9595-1&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2210000001990233602%22%7D) cheaper